# Before&After purchase of a product

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, product, purchase-order

I have two tables:

- orders_product: all the orders. Each line is a product sold with some details about the order in which it was included. So, if the order has more than 1 product, there are more than 1 line for this order.
- orders_grouped: each line is an order with some details about this specific order.

I would like know if there was a previous purchase and a following purchase for each product.

```
SELECT
  product_name,
  last_value(product_all_grouped_list) over (partition by ord.customer_id order by created_at asc rows  between unbounded preceding and 1  preceding ) as last_order,
  last_value(product_all_grouped_list) over (partition by ord.customer_id order by created_at desc rows  between unbounded preceding and 1  preceding ) as next_order_products,
  last_value(basket_size) over (partition by ord.customer_id order by created_at desc rows  between unbounded preceding and 1  preceding ) as next_order_basket_size

FROM
  `orders_product` ord
  left join `orders_grouped` ordgroup 
on ord.order_number=ordgroup.order_number
```

When the order has only one product (basket_size=1), everything is correct but when the basket_size>1, the results for the first product of this order is OK but for the rest of products of the order is wrong.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Because several orders items are present and thus several rows the windows function has to be different.

`RANGE` instead of `ROWS` in the `over` statement.

Also use `window` at the end:

```sql
With tbl as (
  Select * from unnest(generate_timestamp_array("2022-09-01","2022-09-15",interval 1 hour)) update_time
)

SELECT
  *,
  LAST_VALUE(update_time) OVER (ORDER BY update_time ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING ),
  timestamp_diff(update_time,timestamp("1999-01-01"),second) ,
  LAST_VALUE(update_time) OVER SETUP_window
FROM
  tbl
  window SETUP_window as (ORDER BY timestamp_diff(update_time,timestamp("1999-01-01"),second) ASC RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 36000 PRECEDING )
  order by update_time desc
```

Comment: thank you Samuel. I didn't understand well your answer but tried to follow your step and I got the following message: "Query error: ORDER BY key must be numeric in a RANGE-based window with OFFSET PRECEDING or OFFSET FOLLOWING boundaries, but has type TIMESTAMP"

Comment: There is the need to transform timestamp to a number for the `order by` statement `timestamp_diff(update_time,timestamp("1999-01-01"),second)`